# About Disposing DataContext and DataBind()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, idisposable

So, if I have some method to return a list of products:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> List()
    {
        try
        {
            using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext ())
            {
                return db.Products.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

When I set, let's say, a `Repeater` to have this as it's datasource:

```
protected void LoadList()
{
     BusProducts products = new BusProducts();
     rptProducts.DataSource = products.List();
     rptProducts.DataBind();
 }
```

I get an error on the `DataBind()` saying that I can't access the Disposed Object (MyDataContext)..

Is this right? Even if I'm returning all with `.ToList()` ?

Comment: What is the purpose of your try catch? it is simply "swallowing" your exception. I wonder if you are encountering some type of SQL issue which will most likely require you to look at the inner exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referencing any of the Product entities' navigation properties (related parent or child entities) as a result of the binding, then yes you will get that exception even with the ToList. This is because accessing the navigation properties will require additional queries to the database at the time the property is accessed. That won't work if the DataContext has been disposed.

You can avoid this by having the related data eagerly loaded when the product data is retrieved. This is accomplished with the prefetching mechanism - DataContext.LoadOptions, using the LoadWith option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb882681%28v=VS.90%29.aspx